# Regarding instantons in 2D Abelian gauge theory

Tags: gauge-theory, instantons

I am trying to understand the analogues of instantons in a $U(1)$ gauge theory in 2D Euclidean spacetime. If we follow the same arguments as the 4D case and say that the the gauge field must tend to pure gauge at infinity, we will get topologically non-trivial configurations. Now, I want an explicit solution for such a configuration. This is where I run into problems. There is no analogue of the self-duality equations in 2 dimensions. If I choose an ansatz for the solution such as $$A_{\theta}=f(r)\big(e^{i\theta}\partial_{\theta}e^{-i\theta}\big)$$ along the with the boundary conditions $f(r=0)=0$ and $f(r \rightarrow \infty)=1$ and try to solve for it using Maxwell's equations, I am not able to get a consistent solution. Can anyone help me in figuring out where I am going wrong? Does such an explicit, analytic solution actually exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can't be any such solutions in the pure gauge theory, but if you have  a Higgs field condensate you will get solutions that are the cross sections of Nielsen-Oleson (or Abrikosov) vortex lines.

The 2d euclidean Maxwell equations are the same as those for   $t$ and $z$-independent magnetic fields $B_z=F_{12}$ in 3+1d. You can't have a static  flux lump of  magnetic field  without a current somewhere. To be precise
$$
\partial_x B_z  =-J_y, \quad \partial_y B_z=J_x
$$
so unless $F_{1,2}=B_z$ is to be constant, there has to be a current.

Comment: That's what I thought too. But what would be the reason for the absence of such solutions?

Comment: I'll amend my answer to add this